# cordova not installing -win8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-8.1

I like to use Ionic on win8.1, so I'm trying to install Cordova with no success. I already installed Nodejs and Ionic.
First, when installing Cordova I was getting errors on every line after the     **npm install -g cordova** line in command prompt, now I'm getting this on the screenshot after typing **npm cache clean** and the cordova install line

**EDIT**: tried with npm install -g cordova ionic, installed nicely, but I still get the "Unable to add plugins, Perhaps your version of Cordova is too old"error, even tried to add plugman and git folders in AppData/Local/Temp

[image]

Comment: Try `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.eu` then `npm install -g cordova`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this line to PATH in System Variables:
**C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem**

also, added **C:\directory\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin** folder in the PATH in System Variables